# Ruby Sinatra storing variables

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, routes, sinatra

In the code below, the initial get '/' contains a form, whose action is post '/'. when the user inputs a number, it should be converted to a variable that will be used to call the Game class, for which I have generated another action to reveal a new form at get '/game'. the variable generated in the post method is not being stored. how can I both store the variable created in post and then link into the get  '/game' action?

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
@@count = 5
Dict = File.open("enable.txt")

class Game
   attr_accessor :letters, :number, :guess, :disp
   @@count = 5

   def initialize (number)
     letters = find(number) 
   end

   def find (n)
     words =[]
     dictionary = File.read(Dict)  
     dictionary.scan(/\w+/).each {|word| words << word if word.length == n}
     letters = words.sample.split("").to_a 
     letters
   end

   def counter
         if letters.include?guess
            correct = check_guess(guess, letters)
          else
           @@count -= 1
          end
   end
end

get '/' do 
   erb :index
end

post '/' do 
  n = params['number'].to_i
  @letters = Game.new(n) 
  redirect '/game' 
end

get "/game" do 


   guess = params['guess']
   letters = @letters
   if guess != nil
     correct = check_guess(guess, letters)
   end
   disp = display(letters, correct)          

   erb :game, :locals => {:letters => letters, :disp => disp}  

end



   def display(letters, correct)
     line = "__"
     d=[]
     letters.each do |x| 
       if correct == nil
         d << line
       elsif correct.include?x  
         d << x  
       else
         d << line
       end
     end
     d.join(" ")
   end 


   def check_guess(guess, letters)
     correct = [] 
     if guess != nil   
       if letters.include?guess
         correct << guess
       end
     end
     correct
   end
```

Comment: Please edit your question with proper formatting.

Comment: Thankyou, how do you get it to work like that? I mean to get all the code into the window- box?

Comment: Is there a reason that you dont have the form post to /game and do that processing in that block of code?

Comment: Actually yes, because I want to store the value generated in the post '/' do action only once, so that it does not change each time I get '/game' as that will generate another form that will be submitted multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
@letters = Game.new(n)
```

each time you create a request, and new Request instance created and so the `@letters` attribute no longer exists.

It's the equivalent of

```
r = Request.new()
r.letters = Game.new()

r = Request.new()
r.letters  # not defined anymore!!
```

You could achieve what you want using a class variable instead

```
@@letters = Game.new(n)
```

Although this will become a nightmare when you have multiple users and will only work when you have a single ruby server process.

A more advanced approach would be to store `params['number']` in a session cookie or in a database.